# git how to apply patch generated from git diff --no-index /backup /source

Tags: git

i'm working on a large project, which consists of many git repos, and also bunch of files/dirs not tracked by git. i'm using `sed -i.bak` to apply mass changes, which created lots of .bak files

to avoid modifying files/dirs not tracked by git, i created a `backup` folder somewhere else, moved all .bak files to `backup` folder, rename them to original file names

i created `big.patch` by `git diff --no-index backup/file source/file` to all files in `backup` folder. i believe in this way the patch is complete, which should include files tracked by git and files not tracked by git

**update**: when generating patch file, there were many warning messages: `warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in /path/to/source/filename.`

i'm planning to revert back the `source` folder from `backup` folder, and just keep the big patch file

how do i apply this big patch file which includes patches for multiple git repos and files/folders not tracked by git, to `source` folder?

i've tried `git apply --check big.patch`, there's error like

`error: git diff header lacks filename information when removing 1 leading pathname component (line 34581)`

patch content around line 34581

```
diff --git a/path/to/backup/1.html b/path/to/source/1.html
index 109deee..7e41088 100644
--- a/path/to/backup/1.html
+++ b/path/to/source/1.html
@@ -5,7 +5,7 @@ Do Not Edit! -->
 <TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
 <H1>Bookmarks</H1>
 <DL><p>
-    <DT><A HREF="https://www.google.com/" ADD_DATE="1424779391" LAST_VISIT="1424779391" LAST_MODIFIED="1424779392" ICON_URI="https://www.google.com/favicon.ico" >Google</A>
+    <DT><A HREF="https://www.notgoogle.com/" ADD_DATE="1424779391" LAST_VISIT="1424779391" LAST_MODIFIED="1424779392" ICON_URI="https://www.google.com/favicon.ico" >Google</A>
     <DT><A HREF="https://login.live.com/" ADD_DATE="1424779398" LAST_VISIT="1424779398" LAST_MODIFIED="1424779398" ICON_URI="https://auth.gfx.ms/16.000.25462.00/favicon.ico?v=2" >Outlook</A>
     <DT><A HREF="http://www.speedtest.net/" ADD_DATE="1424779406" LAST_VISIT="1424779406" LAST_MODIFIED="1424779406" ICON_URI="http://www.speedtest.net/favicon.ico" >Speed Test</A>
 </DL><p>
diff --git a/some/other/file ....
```

line#34581 is  `<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>`

updated per @hackape 's solution:

after changing path in patch file, new error message:

`error: patch fragment without header at line 243725: @@ -184,7 +184,7 @@ Error<BR>`

patch content near line 243725

```
diff --git a/source/1.txt b/source/1.txt
index d306c79..51024d7 100644
--- a/source/1.txt
+++ b/source/1.txt
@@ -1311,7 +1311,7 @@ Tests DOMSnapshot.getSnapshot method.
             attributes : [
                 [0] : {
                     name : href
-                    value : https://www.google.com/
+                    value : https://www.notgoogle.com/
                 }
             ]
             backendNodeId : <number>
```

line 243725 is                          `name : href`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUIC, you made changes right in `source/` files but also keep a `backup/` snapshot, now you want to restore `source/` to their original state before changes.

Here's a simple git setup to demonstrate:

```
.
├── backup
│   └── foo.txt # bar
└── source
    └── foo.txt # zoo
```

So original content of `source/foo.txt` is `bar`, now changed to `zoo`. `backup/foo.txt` is still `bar`.

First run `git diff --no-index backup/* source/* > big.patch` and get the patch:

```
diff --git a/backup/foo.txt b/source/foo.txt
index 5716ca5..d15dc45 100644
--- a/backup/foo.txt
+++ b/source/foo.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-bar
+zoo
```

Second replace all `a/backup` occurrence in `big.patch` to `a/source`, we got:

```
diff --git a/source/foo.txt b/source/foo.txt
index 5716ca5..d15dc45 100644
--- a/source/foo.txt
+++ b/source/foo.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-bar
+zoo
```

Last reverse apply the patch with `git apply big.patch --reverse`. This will restore `source/` back to original state, identical to `backup/`. And if you run `git apply big.patch` at this point, it will apply the mass changes.

Comment: thank you, after changing path to source in patch file, the old error message is gone, but there's new error `error: patch fragment without header at line 243725: @@ -184,7 +184,7 @@ Error<BR>`

Comment: i updated question with new error and patch content near error line number

Comment: the error is complaining about `@@ -184,7 +184,7 @@ Error<BR>` , but the content you paste doesn't match. I'm not sure why the line number mismatch, problem may sit somewhere else. Try lookahead of this section.

Comment: thanks, i don't know why git is reporting different line number, when i search by `@@ -184,7 +184,7 @@ Error<BR>`, i found 2 places trying to update a gif file, i opened the gif file with text edit, it seems to be a text file, but i'm not 100% sure

Comment: thanks, i optimized my scripts, and generated a new patch file, it's working now